# Multiple table combined PIVOT table using SQL

Tags: sql

I have multiple tables in my data set. I need two columns from one table to be pivoted against one column in a different table.

Code:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 

  table1.name,  

  table6.count,
  table6.car_name 


From Master_Table   

Inner Join table1 
        On Master_Table.ID_SEQNO = table1.ID_SEQNO
Inner Join table2 
        On table1.table1_ID_SEQNO = table2.table1_ID_SEQNO

Inner Join table3
        On table2.ID_SEQNO = table3.ID_SEQNO

Inner Join table4
        On table3.ID_SEQNO = table4.ID_SEQNO



Left Outer Join table5
        On table4.CANDIDATE_ID_SEQNO = table5.CANDIDATE_ID_SEQNO

Left Outer Join table6
        On table5.ID_SEQNO = table6.ID_SEQNO


ORDER BY table1.name
```

Output I need:

[image]

What I have now :

[image]

```
Master_Table : Has names , Date, Time of ownership etc
table1 has info on each name , adress phone number email etc
 table2 has info like cars insurance etc so on... I have used id_seqno to join statements without which the code doesn't work.
```

Each table has a id_seqno  with which I map it to every other table... I am modifying an existing code so pretty new to this.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Ok . I haven't posted in a while. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Where is `table5` defined in your query?

Comment: You would probably need to show us sample data in order to receive an accurate answer.

Comment: That query is invalid and should raise an error. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Make it possible to assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your query and your results basically have nothing to do with each other -- columnwise.  Hence, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Gordon , If I have the second image as a table how do I get the first one? I think Pivot is the way to do it. But anything I look up is not working. Do I need additional module to be installed to use tablefunc or pivot?